# Redis encoding of objects and the size impact

Tags: memory, redis, redis-cli, redis-cache

When I write some objects to redis I can get different memory usage stats. I want to understand how this happens.

Simple example:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set a 1
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> MEMORY usage a
(integer) 49
127.0.0.1:6379> set a "1"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> MEMORY usage a
(integer) 49
127.0.0.1:6379> set a \x01 <<<< Message packed of number 1
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> MEMORY usage a
(integer) 55
127.0.0.1:6379> set a '\x01' <<<< Message pack of number 1 but added '' 
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> MEMORY usage a
(integer) 55
127.0.0.1:6379> set a "\x01" <<<<< Message pack of number 1 but added "" 
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> MEMORY usage a
(integer) 52
```

and the encoding each time (as a embstr):

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set a 1
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> DEBUG OBJECT a
Value at:0x7f9858217ba0 refcount:2147483647 encoding:int serializedlength:2 lru:11691925 lru_seconds_idle:222
127.0.0.1:6379> set a "1"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> DEBUG OBJECT a
Value at:0x7f9858217ba0 refcount:2147483647 encoding:int serializedlength:2 lru:11692152 lru_seconds_idle:1
127.0.0.1:6379> set a \x01
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> DEBUG OBJECT a
Value at:0x7f98563a1398 refcount:1 encoding:embstr serializedlength:5 lru:11692162 lru_seconds_idle:0
127.0.0.1:6379> set a '\x01'
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> DEBUG OBJECT a
Value at:0x7f98563a13e0 refcount:1 encoding:embstr serializedlength:5 lru:11692168 lru_seconds_idle:1
127.0.0.1:6379> set a "\x01"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> DEBUG OBJECT a
Value at:0x7f98563a1788 refcount:1 encoding:embstr serializedlength:2 lru:11692177 lru_seconds_idle:1
```

A bit more complex value (string with a number)

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set a "abc123"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> DEBUG OBJECT a
Value at:0x7f985821b260 refcount:1 encoding:embstr serializedlength:7 lru:11692243 lru_seconds_idle:3
127.0.0.1:6379> MEMORY usage a
(integer) 57
127.0.0.1:6379> set a \xa6abc123
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> MEMORY usage a
(integer) 61
127.0.0.1:6379> DEBUG OBJECT a
Value at:0x7f985821b320 refcount:1 encoding:embstr serializedlength:11 lru:11692273 lru_seconds_idle:9
127.0.0.1:6379> set a "\xa6abc123"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> MEMORY usage a
(integer) 58
127.0.0.1:6379> DEBUG OBJECT a
Value at:0x7f985821b260 refcount:1 encoding:embstr serializedlength:8 lru:11692291 lru_seconds_idle:11
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

And a large JSON string (and then message packed) , the encoding is "raw"

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set a '[{"id":1,"first_name":"Kyrstin","last_name":"Ifill","email":"kifill0@livejournal.com","count":93,"ip_address":"182.218.153.253"}]'
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> DEBUG OBJECT a
Value at:0x7f98582b96f0 refcount:1 encoding:raw serializedlength:128 lru:11692490 lru_seconds_idle:2
127.0.0.1:6379> MEMORY usage a
(integer) 182
127.0.0.1:6379> set a '\x91\x86\xa5count]\xaafirst_name\xa7Kyrstin\xa9last_name\xa5Ifill\xa5email\xb7kifill0@livejournal.com\xaaip_address\xaf182.218.153.253\xa2id\x01'
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> MEMORY usage a
(integer) 197
127.0.0.1:6379> DEBUG OBJECT a
Value at:0x7f98582b9700 refcount:1 encoding:raw serializedlength:143 lru:11692517 lru_seconds_idle:6
127.0.0.1:6379> set a "\x91\x86\xa5count]\xaafirst_name\xa7Kyrstin\xa9last_name\xa5Ifill\xa5email\xb7kifill0@livejournal.com\xaaip_address\xaf182.218.153.253\xa2id\x01"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> DEBUG OBJECT a
Value at:0x7f98582b96f0 refcount:1 encoding:raw serializedlength:107 lru:11692535 lru_seconds_idle:2
127.0.0.1:6379> MEMORY usage a
(integer) 158
```

Answer (score 5):

**This answer based on Redis 4.0, on a bit-64 machine**

In order to be memory efficient, Redis encodes value string in three methods:

1. ***Int***: If the value string can be converted to an integer, e.g. `-2^63` ~ `2^63`, Redis saves the value as an integer. This is the most efficient encoding.
2. ***Embeded String***: If the size of the value string is less than or equal to `44` bytes, Redis saves the string in the same chunk of the Redis object itself. This is more memory efficient than the `Raw String` encoding. Also, it's more cache-friendly. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74052557/how-to-explain-the-redis-embstr-is-more-efficiency-than-raw-data-type/74053532#74053532) for the reason.
3. ***Raw String***: Otherwise, Redis uses the raw encoding.

In your cases:

1. `set a 1` and `set a "1"`: The value is a string that can be converted to `1`. So Redis use ***Int*** encoding, i.e. `encoding:int`.
2. `set a \x01` and `set a '\x01'`: The value is a string with `4` characters （NOTE: since the string is enclosed in single quotes, it won't be escaped）. It cannot be converted to an integer, and its size is less than `44`. So Redis use ***Embeded String*** encoding, i.e. `encoding:embstr`.
3. `set a "\x01"`: Since the string is enclosed in double quotes, the value is escaped as a binary string, whose length, i.e. `1` bytes, is less than `44`, and cannot be converted to integer. So Redis use ***Embeded String*** encoding, i.e. `encoding:embstr`.
4. Set a large json string: The value is a string whose size is greater than `44`. So Redis use ***Raw String*** encoding, i.e. `encoding:raw`.

Comment: I think in "3" you mean it can be converted to an integer right? And what about the case where you mix a string and a binary string together? i.e. "mylongkeykeyabc1234" has a different memory footprint than "mylongkeykeyabc\xcd\x04\xd2"

Comment: No, "\x01" CANNOT be converted to an integer. It's different from "1", whose ASCII code is "\x31".  So `set a "\x31"` is the same as `set a 1`.

Comment: If you mix ascii string and binary string, Redis will use *Embeded String* or *Raw String* encoding, depends on the string length. In your case, `mylongkeykeyabc1234` is one byte longer than `mylongkeykeyabc\xcd\x04\xd2`, because of string escape. So they have different memory footprint.